# How to use Acceleo and Sirius?

Tags: xml, dsl, acceleo

I want to generate code with Acceleo 3.4.x where my metamodel is custom DSL created with Sirius project. Created Sirius diagram is split into two files: aird file for graphical data, and one file for semantic data which is practically XML file.

Here are my questions:

1. What is metamodel URI if I'm using Sirius diagram?
2. Are there any examples for Acceleo and Sirius? Or example of something similar to this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it.

In Eclispe runtime you have a project with model that is based on earlier defined Domain Model. That model is created graphically with Sirius and it has the extension in the form of a name of Domain Model.

For example: if Domain Model is named MyClassModel, that is what you are looking for when you work with Acceleo.

So, when you create new Acceleo project, you can choose metamodel URI and that will be, following the example: myclassmodel.

The trick is that you can choose URI from development time version and runtime version. Runtime version is the choice cause youre model is in Eclipse runtime. That's it for metamodel URI.

Now, before mentioned modeling project you can export from Eclipse runtime and import in Eclipse development time. That will be important when you want to generate code and Acceleo asks you for the import model. Since your model.myclassmodel from modeling project is now in development version, you can easily find it and choose it.

That is how it worked for me.